# Fancybox2 does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I've been trying to get fancybox 2 to work for ages.

Eventually I've gotten to the point of just trying a basic example on jsfiddle.

I call fancybox via:

`$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });​`

and the html looks like:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" /></a>​
```

The code is taken from fancybox's own site, just grabbing some placeholder images from lorempixel.

I've attached the to the fiddle the required fancybox css and js, and told it to use jquery 1.7.2

Could someone please take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong? It's driving me crazy that I can't even get the basic example to work.

[You can find the fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mnuRw/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: I disagree with @DavidMuller ... his answer is a workaround but you may find the same issue in another situations. Please see my answer.

Comment: Just a heads-up for anyone working with Concrete5. Some addons load their own version of libraries, such as fancybox. You can not use more than one addon which use these libraries without modifying the addons yourself. 

In my case, I switched from fancybox2 to yoxview, and everything works (because no addons load yoxview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**<Update>**

As JFK stated in his answer, the problem is that fancybox could not determine the content type because there is no extension on the lorempixel-url.

**</Update>**

Phew, took me quite a long time to figure this out. The problem is indeed the "lorempixel.com" service. I have updated the fiddle to a "real" image and voilà ;).

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8434/7786420744_8a1f692248_c.jpg"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8434/7786420744_8a1f692248_c.jpg"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" /></a>
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/mnuRw/3/

Comment: This frustrates me. I've spent maybe 2 days banging my head against this problem. I never even thought to check lorempixel.

Comment: haha, I'm feeling with you. I was also very confused what is wrong with the code for some time...

Comment: `The problem is indeed the "lorempixel.com" service` ... well, is not, indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with @DavidMuller ... the problem is not the `lorempixel.com` service. The real problem is that fancybox cannot figure out the `type` of content from the url

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" /></a>​
```

... because it doesn't have an image extension (either `jpg`, `png` or `gif`) so you have to tell that is an `image`.

You have different options to set the `type` of content

1). Use the `type` API option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "image"
    });
});​
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y6ktT/)**

2). use the `data-fancybox-type` (HTML5) attribute

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="image" rel="group" href="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/" alt="" /></a>​
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vf9UN/1/)**

For more information, check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support FAQ tab, No. 5

Comment: Good to know! I have never used fancybox2 before so I was a litle confused about that.

Comment: Thanks JFK, I thought Fancybox would simply show a blank box when it encountered an unknown media type.